# How do I use getField to return in a different format with Java? Adobe PDF - mm/dd/yyyy to dd

Tags: javascript, java, date, pdf, adobe

I am trying to create a form where you select a date in one field (output is mm/dd/yyyy), then will populate the dd, mmmm, yy into 3 separate fields within Adobe PDF Editor. I am VERY naive concerning Javascript and am trying to piece this together and learn on my own. I'm spinning tires Googling this, so can anyone help?

If I use the below code to pull from a field I have labeled Date, and change the format to mmmm, this cell works. But if I change the format to dd or yy, it will only return mm.

event.value = this.getField("Date").valueAsString;

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely unrelated.

Comment: Good to know! Again, naive.. Got any solutions for me by chance though? lol

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var selectedDate = this.getField("Date").valueAsString;
var dateObj = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", selectedDate); //parse the selected date string

if (dateObj) {
  //extract day, month, and year from the date object
  var day = util.printd("dd", dateObj);
  var month = util.printd("mmmm", dateObj);
  var year = util.printd("yy", dateObj);

  //populate the respcetive fiedls with the extracted values
  this.getField("Day").value = day;
  this.getField("Month").value = month;
  this.getField("Year").value = year;
}
```

In this code, replace "Date" with the name or ID of the field that contains the selected date, and replace "Day," "Month," and "Year" with the names or IDs of the fields where you want to populate the day, month, and year components, respectively.

mke sure to place this code in the appropriate event handler of the "Date" field. 4 example, you can place it in the "OnBlur" event handler to trigger the population of the other fields when the focuss moves away from the "Date" field. i hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Jefa, so so much!! That worked for day, did not for month for some reason.. and worked for year, until I changed the year to 2024 as a test. I changed month back to my original code and changed name to Month1, so it works again, but Year I cannot get to work correctly outside of 2023 calendar.